# Python GTK does not show menubar

Tags: python, gtk, menubar

I am a PHP programmer, and want to get into writing Python GUI apps under Linux.

On my Ubuntu 12.04 computer, with any version of PyGtk the MenuBar simply does not show. 
On my Ubuntu 10.04 computer at work, with exactly the same code, the MenuBar always shows.

I am trying to learn the up to date way of doing things, so have been using the example at the bottom of this page:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html

I assume one of you will know the issue straight off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doh !

Ubuntu 12.04 uses Unity, and Unity shows the menu at the top of the desktop.

Doh again !

Answer (score 2):

You can find the following answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1935380) :

> In Unity you can disable the global menu for your program by setting
>   the environment variable $UBUNTU_MENUPROXY to 0 (or anything else that
>   is not "libappmenu.so"). So if for some reason you want to make sure
>   that even in Unity your app shows the menu inside the app window just
>   create a small wrapper shell script that unsets $UBUNTU_MENUPROXY and
>   starts your program.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 for pygtk application, you even do not have to create shell script, just change os.environ before importing gtk:
import os
os.environ['UBUNTU_MENUPROXY']='0'

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem but in a C++ project on Ubuntu. I have managed to work around by setting the gtk-shell-shows-menubar property to FALSE as below:

g_object_set(gtk_settings_get_default(),
             "gtk-shell-shows-menubar", FALSE,
             NULL);

You could translate it to python if you would like.